# ShapeShift from Monero to BTC

Tags: monerod

Last night I converted Monero to BTC. I’ve sent it, but not received anything.

Did I do anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you send XMR to ShapeShift and have not received the BTC yet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to the exchange. Please contact the exchange support.